# Speeding up SQL SELECT query for table with 6 million rows

Tags: sql, performance, select

I have a table with only one column and 6 millions rows. Each row contains a string encrypted in PHP (circa 32 chars each).

I have a simple SELECT query which validates the input (if the inserted code (via HTML form) exists in the database, insert it (into another table)).

```
SELECT 1 FROM codes WHERE code = $value
```

It works well, however with 6 million rows, it takes 10 to 15 seconds to validate. Is there some universal approach to this?

Comment: Make code the primary key (assuming that the codes are unique). Your RDBMs will arrange them the best possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be faster if you have the appropriate index:

```
create index idx_codes_code on codes(code)
```

If you have an index, then the issue may be the number of rows being returned.  In that case, you can limit the result set to a single row.  You don't specify the database.  The standard syntax is:

```
SELECT 1
FROM codes
WHERE code = $value
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In some databases, this would be handled with `SELECT TOP (1)` or `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if something exists, consider using EXISTS:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM code WHERE code = $value)
```

This returns after 1 record is found.

Answer (score 0):

Index will take care of the problem.
But if you want response in below 200 ms I would recommend using  an in memory cache